# How to access specific data out of an API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

this is my first time ever working with an API so please bear with me. I am using a node application to try and get some trivia questions out of an API. I when I try to run this function all it does is return undefined. I know that the variable is not supposed to be undefined because when I run `` console.log(`${result.question}`) `` within the map loop it works fine.
Here's the piece of code that keeps messing up:

```
var MappedArray;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple&difficulty=medium';

function generatequestion(mode)
{
fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
  let result = data.results; // Get the results
  MappedArray = result.map(function(result) { // Map through the results and for each run the code below
    switch (mode)
    {
        case 1:
            return `${result.question}`;
            break;
        case 2:
            return `${result.correct_answer}`;
            break;
        case 3:
            return `${result.incorrect_answers}`;
            break;
    }
  })
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});  
}
console.log(generatequestion(1));
```

if you can help me I give many thanks in advance!

Comment: The `json` variable in your code contains a plain javascript object, manipulate it like you'd manipulate any other objects. `json.results[0].category` is `"History"` for example. Please precise your question - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, what I specifically mean is that I can't access the data outside the function for some reason because when I run the function it just returns Undefined. Even when I set a variable from a larger scope to the string it just says undefined.

Comment: Sorry, upon further inspection it seems all I was forgetting was the index in the object notation. A silly mistake, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It will be greatly helpful if you learn more about [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), 
>   [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

The reason you are unable to fetch the data outside of the function is the `console.log()` is not waiting for the `generatequestion` to complete the execution.

It will be nice if you wrap the fetch call in a promise as done below.

```
var MappedArray;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple&difficulty=medium';
function generatequestion(mode) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(function(data) {
        let result = data.results; // Get the results
        MappedArray = result.map(function(result) {
          // Map through the results and for each run the code below
          switch (mode) {
            case 1:
              return `${result.question}`;

            case 2:
              return `${result.correct_answer}`;

            case 3:
              return `${result.incorrect_answers}`;

          }
        });
        resolve(MappedArray);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

(async () => {
  let resp = await generatequestion(1);
  console.log(resp);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, after some further research on MDN, I see what I did wrong. That was really helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the MappedArray after looping.

```js
var MappedArray;
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple&difficulty=medium';

function generatequestion(mode)
{
fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
  let result = data.results; // Get the results
  MappedArray = result.map(function(result) { // Map through the results and for each run the code below
    switch (mode)
    {
        case 1:
            return `${result.question}`;
            break;
        case 2:
            return `${result.correct_answer}`;
            break;
        case 3:
            return `${result.incorrect_answers}`;
            break;
    }
  })
  return MappedArray;
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});  
}
console.log(generatequestion(1));
```